# Save file on a network share C# .Net core 3

Tags: c#, .net-core, unc

I'm trying to save a xml file on a network share, but for some unknown reason the saving process just halts.

ex:
I have a xml document which I want to save as

```
var filename = {guid}.xml
var shareFolder = "\\\\<my machine\\Share";
var filePath = Path.Join(shareFolder,filename);
```

I've checked that

```
Directory.Exists(shareFolder)
```

returns true - so at the very least the folder exists on the share.

The share permission on the folder is set to "write" for Everyone.

I tried to use

```
xml.Save(filePath); 
File.WriteAllText(filePath, xml.OuterXml);
```

But got similar results where the saving process just grinds to an halt. 
The log doesn't tell me anything either.

Comment: Do you mean `@"\\<my machinename>\Share"` (or `"\\\\<my machinename>\\Share"`)?

Comment: I meant of course "\\\\<my machine\\Share"
The share is read from an appSettings file.

Comment: Yeah, I need to do some more clarifying

Comment: What do you mean 'the save process halts'? If you wrap the process in a try-catch, what does the exception say?

Comment: Oh Wow, I really dropped the ball on that one. There's an exception being thrown and it's complaining about credentials.

Comment: What happens with `File.WriteAllText(filePath, "Hello world");`?

Comment: Instead of using `xml.Save()` can you not put it in an asynchronous method and use `await SaveFile(// file passed into the function, // file path)`? This way you won't need the `File.WriteAllText()` line

Comment: Yeah, it's an credential issue @JamesS .. 
I think I read a ton of msdn pages on msdn, trying to find a reasonable way to handle unc. I didn't think it threw an exception, seems like there's an exception catcher somewhere I need to handle. 

Thank you for the good pointer, you as well Klaus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use https://github.com/mj1856/SimpleImpersonation to get the authentication working.

The final result for .Net Core 3.1 looks like this:

```
    private void Process xml(string xmlInput)
    {
            var xmlDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlInput);
            var filename = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}.xml";
            var filePath = Path.Combine(_outputFolder, filename);

            if (filePath.StartsWith("\\"))
            {
                SaveOnNetworkShare(xmlDocument, filePath);
            }
            else
            {
                SaveLocally(xmlDocument, filePath);
            }

    }

    private void SaveLocally(XmlDocument xml, string filePath)
    {
        xml.Save(filePath);
    }

    private void SaveOnNetworkShare(XmlDocument xml, string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            Impersonation.RunAsUser(_credentials, LogonType.Network, () =>
            {
                xml.Save(filePath);
            });
        }
        catch (ImpersonationException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(new EventId(-1, "Error saving file"), ex, $"Could not save file to filepath {filePath}");
        }
    }
```