# How to save a file to network shared directory in .net core hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I always get path not found exception when this happens. I read that .net core runs in Kestrel and doesn't have access to network folders to save the files.

I have setup the application pool to have proper permissions to be able to read and write from the network shared folder but still unable to save the file using File.Copy method in C#.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: IOs Kestrel on Windows or Linux?  You have a credential issue. Not sure what credentials you are using.  Not sure why.  See : https://stackify.com/what-is-kestrel-web-server/?force_isolation=true

Comment: My app is running in Windows server IIS.

Comment: the user account has to be recognized by both local machine, IIS, and Network drive.  Can you save file using a File Explorer.  Get File Explorer working first.

Comment: [Does this answer useful to you ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61595676/7687666)